# In Javascript, can I use == two times in a single condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

what I meant is whether I was able to, for instance, type:

```
     if(numb1 == numb2 == numb3){
        //exec code
     }
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: You *can*, but it might not mean what you think.

Comment: Never did. I was just asked. And given my ignorance, I tried you guys :)

Comment: `if(true==false==false) = true` :D

Comment: In short, no. You should never do that.

Comment: The reason you are getting such negative responses is because you in fact *didn't* try...

Comment: What does it mean then?

Comment: @Naza - the real question is what you *want* it to do... What is your intention with this code?

Comment: explaining my example: `true==false==false` is evaluated as `((true==false)==false)` => `(false)==false` ==> `true`

Comment: Lix, I was asked whether the code I posted would result in "true" only when the three variables are the same.

Comment: @Naza No. Actually it can (and in most cases will) produce `false` even if all three variables are the same.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment:

> You *can*, but it might not mean what you think.

It "translates" to:

```
if( (numb1 == numb2) == numb3)
```

`==` can be thought of as a function, that takes two arguments and returns `true` if they are equal. So your code would be:

```
if( [true or false] == numb3)
```

This will work only if `numb3` is a boolean, corresponding to the (in)equality of `numb1` and `numb2`. If you wanted to check if the elements are equal, this is *not* the way to do it.

---

To check if all elements of an array are equal, try this:

```
function array_elements_equal(arr) {
    if( arr.length < 2) return true;
    var l = arr.length, i;
    for( i=1; i<l; i++) {
        if( arr[0] != arr[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var arr = [numb1, numb2, numb3];
if( array_elements_equal(arr)) {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

---

And now for some random fun:

```
0==0              // true
0==0==0           // false
0==0==0==0        // true
0==0==0==0==0     // false
0==0==0==0==0==0  // true
...
```

Comment: @freakish Not quite - `2 == 2 == 2` produces `false` because `true == 2` is `false`.

Comment: Yeah, not really truthy, however `1==1==1`, because `true==1` or `true=="1"`. Also `true==[1]` (reminds me why I hate JavaScript, that's some really funky stuff) and probably lots of other cases? Anyway this syntax should be avoided at all costs IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You *can*, that doesn't necessarily mean it will evaluate to be exactly what you're expecting.

**Side note**: Usually, we'd have to take into account Javascript's [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) but since we're only working with one type of operator, it's irrelevant and the statement is simply evaluated from left to right.

`true == true == true` will certainly evaluate to `true`, because the first part of the statement (`true == true`) evaluates to `true`, which is then compared to the third operator (effectively making the remaining comparison `true == true`), which will evaluate to `true` itself.

**However,** this gets to be a problem when situations like the following arise:

```
true == false == false
```

Certainly, this must evaluate to `false`! But, upon further inspection, the result is `true`. Why? This is effectively the same as stating

```
(true == false) == false
      ^^
   false == false
         ^^
        true
```

In short: be careful when you use operators in this manner, as **they do not operate as you might think**. In most situations, you'd be better off separating your statements into multiple conditionals.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtLZp/)

Comment: Just for clarity, not all operators will be evaluated from left-to-right by default. Other operators might evaluate from right-to-left, this is what MDN calls "Associativity".